# how do i make a liquid div?

Tags: html, css

i'd like to make a liquid box with rounded corners.
i tried [this](http://woork.blogspot.com/2007/12/liquid-layer-with-rounded-corners-using.html) example. The problem i have with this example - it extends to the width of viewport! i tried removing `width:100%` from `div.w1` selector but it didn't help..
I want this box to be as flexible as possible. it should only extend its width and/or height depending on the size of content in `div.w4` .

how do i do that??

Comment: Can you post some of your HTML?

Comment: my html is exactly like one on the page i provided a link to...

Comment: It's still good practice to include what you are referencing/using, in case the link goes bad. http://jsfiddle.net/Mdce8/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it should only extend its width and/or
>   height depending on the size of
>   content in div.w4

You should replace `width: 100%` with either `float: left` or `display: inline-block`.

Either of those will give you the "shrink-wrap" behaviour you desire.

`float: left`: http://jsfiddle.net/MvNWV/

`display: inline-block`: http://jsfiddle.net/MvNWV/1/

---

Just as an aside, did you know that CSS provides native rounded corners?

`border-radius`: http://jsfiddle.net/MvNWV/2/

http://caniuse.com/border-radius - they're supported "everywhere", except in IE older than version 9.

For those browsers, you can use [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/.).

Comment: but why did it extend to the width of viewport, even without width:100%??

Comment: Because `div`s are block-level elements. The default `width` value is `auto`, which for a block-level element means "take the full available width".

Comment: yes.. i'm aware of native rounded corners.. but css3 isn't supported crossbrowserly yet...

Answer (score 1):

remove **width:100%** and add **display:inline-block** to div.w1

see this example:http://jsfiddle.net/p3mM5/

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are attempting to do it the hard way.  If you use CSS3 you're life will be a lot happier. :)

The "easiest" way would be to use this awesome CSS3 generator: [http://css3generator.com](http://css3generator.com/), but its better that you learn to code it, which honestly, is very easy as well:

```
.myClass {
display:block;
width:90%; /*or whatever width you want, add margin if you want, w/e. */
height:90%; /*same as above */
border-radius:5px /*you can set it to however many pixels you like*/
-moz-border-radius:5px; /*mozilla support*/
-webkit-border-radius:5px; /*webkit browser support*/ 
border:1px solid #000; /*change the border thickness and color as you like*/
}
```

Hope this helps.

DC